# How to prove or disprove matrix $A$ is invertible $\iff$ $\det{A}\ne 0$ if it's defined over field $F_p$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces, determinant

How to prove or disprove matrix $A$ is invertible $\iff$  $\det{A}\ne 0$ if it's defined over field $F_p$

What's special about $A$ if it's defined over field $F_p$?

For normal procedure, we have $A$ is invertible $\iff$ $A$ is bijective $\iff$ $\ker{A}={0}$ $\iff$ rank $A$ is full $\iff$ $\det{A}\ne 0$.

Comment: There's nothing really special about $\mathbb F_p$ in this case - it's true for any field $F$.

Comment: Lots of ways to do this. What do you know about determinants? Matrix algebra? Linear transformations?

Comment: What means "normal procedure"?

Comment: The simplest way to do this is $\det A \det A^{-1} = \det I = 1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like Thomas says, for any field $F$, a matrix $A\in{\sf M}_{n\times n}(F)$ 
is invertible if and only if $\det(A)\neq 0$.

If $A$ is invertible, by using the property that
$\det(AB)=\det(A)\cdot\det(B)$,
$$1=\det(I_n)=\det(AA^{-1})=\det(A)\cdot\det(A^{-1}).$$
This gives $\det(A)\neq 0$. Conversely, if $A$ is not invertible, then the rows of $A$ is linearly
dependent. Let the $i$th row of $A$ be obtained by a finite sequence of 
adding a multiple of row of $A$, then we may obtain
$B\in{\sf M}_{n\times n}(F)$ such that the $i$th row of $B$ is a zero vector and other rows are those
in $A$. Thus
$$\det(A)=\det(B)=0. $$